# Angular material input field not working inside mat-list or mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

Hi I have a code like this:

```
 <div class="material-input">
      <mat-form-field class="form-group" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
        <input matInput readonly formControlName="firstName">
        <mat-list *ngFor="let username of mockLdap | async">
          {{username.firstName}}
        </mat-list>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientService, Employee } from '../service/http-client.service';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormsModule, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { LDAPUsers } from "../LDAPUsers";
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-employee',
  templateUrl: './add-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-employee.component.css'],
})
export class AddEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  LDAPUsers: LDAPUsers;
  ldapUsers: Observable<LDAPUsers[]>;
  user: FormGroup;
  mockLdap: Observable<LDAPUsers[]>;
  private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private httpClientService: HttpClientService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder

  ) { }

  search(term: string): void {
    this.searchTerms.next(term);
    console.log(term);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      userName: [''],
      firstName: [''],
      lastName: [''],
      mobile: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    });

   this.httpClientService.getLDAPUser('username').subscribe
      (data => {
        this.LDAPUsers = data;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        this.user.patchValue(data);
      }
      )

createEmployee() //some code here
}
```

MY goal is to have the `input` field inside the `mat-list` tag or combine them somehow because right now it functions like the received data gets into the mat-list field which is shown on my page but the input fields data is sent when i press submit which is empty. Everything I tried so far resulted in errors. I tried removing the input tag or put it inside a `mat-form-field` and then inside the `mat-list` but none worked. If any one has some kind of solution it would help me a lot.

Comment: Paste your ts code as well.

Comment: added my ts code

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: if i put ```input``` inside ```mat-list``` it says: ERROR Error: "mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl."

Answer (score 0):

Have you add MatInputModule in your module?

Comment: yes the first thing was to check if i have every module that is needed in my app.module.ts

Comment: Please try this one.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp9qwl

Comment: yes that example works fine but if i modify mine like the example is my code crashes

Comment: can you edit this one in stackblitz and share that link here?. It may help to find out the issue.